# XML Parsing Without using any delegate methods of nsxmlparser class

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios-simulator, xml-parsing

I don't want to use nsxmlparser delegate methods. I want to write my own methods for xml parsing. How can I parse xml file?

Comment: if you don't know how to parse xml, you are better off using a library then try to roll your own ....

Comment: __Why__? What do you have against using a delegate? Do you think that you code is somehow going to be better than the tested library Apple provide and support? What if you run into problems - you can't ask for help because we don't know your code.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand what is the point of not using delegate. Well, you have 2 options:

1. Use another parser
2. Use NSString methods to separate your XML on tokens and then parse them.

Comment: Any kind of example or some tips regarding it?

Comment: Nope, I prefer the light side: using the NSXMLParser delegate :)

Comment: Or please tell why do you want do your own parsing?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do any parsing you can let NSDictionary do it for you,

```
+ (id)dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path
+ (id)dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)aURL

[xml objectForKey:@"tagName"];
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure these methods don't parse arbitrary XML.

Comment: Not arbritrary, but if the guy can control the XML then this could be a possible solution.

Comment: Those methods of NSDictionary parse a plist, which is usually stored in a specific XML format.  It is XML input, but not arbitrary XML input.

Answer (score 0):

There's absolutely no reason why you should try to avoid the delegate.  If you're wanting to avoid `NSXMLParser`, try a DOM-based parser such as TBXML.  However, `NSXMLParser` is pretty dead-simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google lib called GDataXMLNode (https://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Source/XMLSupport/).

Very easy to use, quite similar to DOM.
And no delegate   ; )